# AssociationTypeMismatch: Tag expected, got "tag1" which is an instance of String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    tags = post_params[:tags]
    @post.user_id = @current_user.id
  
    if @post.save
      tags.each do |tag|
        @post.tags << Tag.find_or_create_by(name: tag)
      end
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end
```

The JSON request I sent.

```
{
    "post": {
    "title":"nth post",
    "body":"content of nth post",
    "tags":["tag1", "tag2"]
    }
}
```

The error I got:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Tag(#93860) expected, got "tag1" which is an instance of String(#2460)):

I implemented almost the exact code a few days ago. It worked then. I thought I had already created a Tag object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is because you are trying to save `@post` instance with `@post = Post.new(post_params)`. And `post_params` contains `"tags":["tag1", "tag2"]`.
I suggest updating your code like:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params.except(:tag))
```